# C# - How to open an Excel application?

Tags: c#, excel

I've managed to add the Excel COM reference, and used the following code:

```
Application myApp = new Application();
```

However, this only opens an Excel app within the context of my C# program. Is it possible to actually open the application for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `myApp.Visible` to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the System.Diagnostics.Process class to run the Excel application